# HasOwnProperty при переборе массива

Tags: javascript

Есть ли необходимость использовать метод hasOwnProperty при переборе элементов массива?

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
for(item in arr) {
    if(arr.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        // некоторый код
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть, сторонние библиотеки и даже расширения браузера могут расширять прототип стандартных объектов. Как раз массивы чаще всего расширяют.

P.S. Лучше не использовать `for in` для массивов совсем.